# How to change css properties of html elements using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I change `CSS` from `javascript`.

I'm using `jQuery-ui Dialog` and I want to change the style of a `DIV` from javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [the jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css). If you want anything it will be there.

Anyhow, if you want to add styles to elements, you need to use the `css` function, which has a few variants.

```
$(selector).css(properties);  // option 1
$(selector).css(name, value); // option 2
```

So if you have a DIV with ID of "mydiv" and you want to make the background red, you would do

```
$("div#mydiv").css({'background-color' : 'red'}); // option 1
$("div#mydiv").css('background-color','red');     // option 2
```

The first way is easier if you're setting multiple things at once.

If you want to check what a property is currently set to, you would use a variant of the 2nd option, just omit the value.

```
var color = $("div#mydiv").css('background-color');
```

Would make the var `color` be `red` if you already set it above, for example.

You can also add and remove classes, doing something like

```
$(selector).addClass(class_name);
$(selector).removeClass(class_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

*This answer works even without jQuery.*

So you have something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .foo { color: Red; }
    .bar { color: Blue; }
</style>
<div class="foo" id="redtext"> some red text here </div>
```

If you wish to change just some attributes, you can always find the element using

```
var div = document.getElementById('redtext');
```

function and then change the attached color style by

```
div.style.color = 'Green';
```

Making your red text appear in green instead.

If you want to change the class defined for the div to another style class, you can do:

```
div.className = 'bar';
```

making the div now use class bar, which makes your previously green text blue.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to manipulate elements styles using the jQuery framework.  Take a look through the documentation related to CSS and changing attributes:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/addClass#class
- http://docs.jquery.com/CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This is jquery code.

```
 $("myDiv").css({"color":"red","display":"block"})
```

If you are using vanila javacript,try this.

```
var myDiv = document,getElementById("myDiv");

myDiv.style.display = "block";

myDiv.style.color = "red";
```